# add classon p tag using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I add css class to p tag only when it has img tag inside.

```
<div id="ReviewLong">

<p>text</p>
<p><img src="1.jpg" alt="" width="600" height="397"/></p>
```

Comment: `$('p:has(img)').addClass('class');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).
In this case the [`:has`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) - selector.

To add the class you'd use the [`.addclass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) method.
Like this:

```
$("p:has(img)").addClass('className')
```

---

I would also advice you to familiarize yourself with the [jQuery DOM manipulation methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/). It can make your life MUCH easier :)

Answer (score 2):

use [`:has`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) to target paragraphs that contain images, and then [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) to add the class

```
$('p:has(img)').addClass('someclass')
```